# jQuery - ending a 'continuous' animation/function

Tags: jquery, animation, loops

I have a function setup to continuously loop an animation as so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function boxGlow() {
        $("#not_bg").animate({opacity:0}, 1000);
        $("#not_bg").animate({opacity:1}, 1000, boxGlow);    
    }
});
```

The snippet works as expected, but I am looking for the most efficient method to cancel the loop when an external div (say `#stopbutton`, for test purposes). So when a user clicks div `#stopbutton`, the `boxGlow()` function will cease, and the opacity reset to 0. Any examples on where to begin are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're using basically a recursive callback. Just setup a loop with `setInterval` and cancel it with `clearInterval`.

Comment: From what I undserstand, once I `clearInterval` I will not be able to re-initiate the loop. Is this true? How can that be avoided or worked around if so?

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way to do it is to set a flag.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var stop = false;

    $('#stopbutton').on('click', function() {
          stop = true;
    });

    function boxGlow() {

        if ( stop ) return;

        $("#not_bg").animate({opacity:0}, 1000);
        $("#not_bg").animate({opacity:1}, 1000, boxGlow);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to do this with javascript timing events: [JavaScript Timing Events](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

 Like this:

```
 $(function()
    {
       var intv = setInterval(function()
       {
          $("#not_bg").animate({opacity:0}, 1000);
          $("#not_bg").animate({opacity:1}, 1000);
       },2000);
       $('#stop').click(function()
       {
          window.clearInterval(intv);
       });
    }};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class to the div when the click event occurs:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#stopbutton').click(function(){
        $('#not_bg').stop().addClass('done').css({opacity:0});
    });
    (function boxGlow() {
        if(!this || !$(this).is('.done')){
            $("#not_bg").animate({opacity:0}, 1000);
            $("#not_bg").animate({opacity:1}, 1000, boxGlow);
        }
    })();
});
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/N42rn/